# how to call spark.stop() old session?

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter, I created spark session like this

```
spark = SparkSession.builder
         .master("yarn")
         .appName("test procjet")
         .getOrCreate()
```

But I forgot `spark.stop()` and shutdown Jupyter notebook. I want to call `stop()` to old session so I tried `getOrCreate()` but spark history server show new application.

How can I get old spark session and stop? I also tried `yarn application -kill <appid>` but spark history still show that.

Comment: if spark is not showing , then it means it is already closed.

Answer (score 1):

When a Jupyter Notebook is shutdown, sparkSession used in that is also stopped as Jupyter is the client which created it. The same is the case when you forget to `close()` SparkSession in a script which uses it.

Comment: Refer Spark Code - [context shutdown hook](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L643)