# PySpark on Windows: How to stop all processes from old Spark session

Tags: pyspark

I installed PySpark and Spyder using Anaconda on Windows 10.  My
`sys.path` includes
`C:\\Users\\User.Name\\anaconda3\\envs\\py39\\lib\\site-packages`,
wherein lies package `pyspark`, of which `sql` is a subpackage.  I
created a SparkSession object in Spyder:

```
In [1]: from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
In [2]: spark = SparkSession.builder \
               .appName("SparkExamples.com").getOrCreate()
```

I was told that the Spark Context Web UI couldn't bind to port 4040,
so it bound (binded?) to 4041:

```
23/09/08 18:40:22 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on
port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
```

Sure enough, there were Web UIs on both 4040 and 4041, with the former
running for 16 hours!  I could stop the new one on 4041:

```
spark.stop()
```

However, the UI on 4040 continues to respond to my web browser.

I've been trying a lot to figure out the ins and outs of running
Spark from Spyder, with limited knowledge of both, and of Python and
Spark.  I started a fresh Spyder session a *lot*, often to create
a SparkSession object.  The old UI on 4040 was probably an attempt
for which I didn't issue `spark.stop()`.

***Short of rebooting the laptop, how can I ensure that all processes
associated with old Spark (and Spyder) sessions are destroyed?***

Following [this
Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445236/how-to-call-spark-stop-old-session),
I already tried `exit()` from the Spyder console as well as closing
the Spyder Windows app.